# How to get the String out of the variable using php?

Tags: php

I have a variable post value and I would like to find it. 
For that I have a for loop and I'm trying to get the post data like that

`$_POST['discount'.$i]`

But when I echo it I get `discount.$i` instant of the value.
What is wrong?

```
for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++){
    if(isset($_POST['discount'.$i]) && isset($_POST['percentage'.$i])){
        $discount[$i] = $_POST['discount'.$i];
        $percentage[$i] = $_POST['percentage'.$i];
        echo '$discount.$i';
        echo '$percentage.$i';
    }
}
```

Comment: share more code how you are using `$_POST['discount'.$i]` ?

Comment: Can you put your form//request code into the question please so we can make some sense of this..

Comment: do this in  two steps: `$s = 'discount'.$i;  echo $_POST[$s]`

Comment: @FrayneKonok Now I know what OP was asking. Thanks!

Comment: yes I will post more moment

Comment: post html and echo statement

Comment: @mastermind99 Frayne Konok just gave your answer

Comment: @mastermind99 please post your html form.

Comment: use like echo $discount[$i]; and echo $percentage[$i];

Comment: @FrayneKonok your comment was pointing out to OP what his POST string was (Which is good debugging).. Nobody told you to post as answer..

Comment: Yes, I thought. `@mastermind99 Frayne Konok just gave your answer – Pogrindis 21 mins ago` is the information for post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    if(isset($_POST['discount' . $i]) && isset($_POST['percentage' . $i]))
    {
        $discount[$i] = $_POST['discount' . $i];
        $percentage[$i] = $_POST['percentage' . $i];
        echo $discount[$i]."<br>";
        echo $percentage[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables **don't expand inside single quotes** (<strike>`echo '$discount.$i'`</strike>) and you need to echo the **array value** `$discount[$i]` **not** <strike>`$discount.$i`</strike>.
 `isset()` allows **empty values** I would use `!empty()` instead, something like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++){
    if(!empty($_POST["discount$i"]) && !empty($_POST["percentage$i"])){
        $discount[$i] = $_POST["discount$i"];
        $percentage[$i] = $_POST["percentage$i"];
        echo $discount[$i];
        echo $percentage[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> As i comment `do this in two steps: $s = 'discount'.$i; echo
>   $_POST[$s]` and has a feedback of 3 votes, I make an answer, and got
>   downvotes, I know the reason of downvotes, Now i make complete answer.

You need to make this two steps. First store in a variable and use the variable inside the `$_POST`.

```
for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++){
    $discounts = 'discount'.$i;
    $percentages = 'percentage'.$i;
    if(isset($_POST[$discounts]) && isset($_POST[$percentages])){
        $discount[$i] = $_POST[$discounts];
        $percentage[$i] = $_POST[$percentages];            
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference ? PS:I didn't down-vote.

Comment: Just to add, this assumes the `POST` var is for example : `name="discount1"` is discount{n}. Which i think is correct.